# Some popular tools are missing in GIMP 2.10 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, plugins, gimp

I am a new user trying to switch from Windows to Linux. I have Ubuntu 20.04 with GIMP 2.10.22 installed. I have also installed the gimp-plugin-registry. But the 'Heal Selection' tool is missing from Filters-Enhance menu. I really need it to work. Please help.

**This question is about the "Heal selection tool"** (found in the Resynthesizer plugin, The one that works like Photoshop's "Content Aware Fill") **not the standard Heal tool**, which the current answer is about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Heal Selection tool

This answer is based on research by @Levente, who insisted I add it to a new answer instead of editing their.

The heal selection tool depends on certain packages which are not available in Ubuntu due to gtk2 being removed, but they can be grabbed from Debian Buster.

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1+b1_amd64.deb
wget https://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gimp/gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1+b1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry
```

I verified that this brings back Heal Selection tool under **Filter -> Enhance** in Gimp 2.10.22 (ppa version) in Ubuntu 20.04.

### Some background

Someone [explains](https://play.datalude.com/blog/2018/11/gimp-2-8-resynthesizer-plugin-ubuntu-18/) how they obtained the Resynthesizer Plugin in Ubuntu 18.04

They mention a `gimp-python` package as dependency for the "Enhance > Heal Selection" menu entry.

This person reports to have [located and installed it](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/gimp-woes-in-20-04/15828/9)
(on 20.04) from the official repositories. But the download links posted by this person shows 404 error. However, Debian still hosts these packages.

It seems that this may be due to GTK2 being deprecated. Luckily GIMP will soon move to GTK3.

Comment: Thank you Archisman! Using below commands worked and I am able to use it now.

wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1+b1_amd64.deb
wget https://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gimp/gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1+b1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb

Comment: @PramodMalawade I am wondering why I am unable to use it (I was able to install, but unable to use the tool. I have posted the error message I got). Anyway, I am glad to know that it works for you.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to mention. I am still trying out different Linux distros. Before you replied, I had already removed Ubuntu and installed Linux Mint. I followed your instructions on Linux Mint and it worked perfectly. I have to say, coming from a Windows background, I loved Linux Mint a lot. Far better than plain old Ubuntu.

Answer (score 12):

### Standard Heal Tool

It is certainly there in Gimp 2.10.22 (which I installed from `ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gimp`), maybe it does not show up because the toolbars are grouped by default.

Go to **Edit -> Preferences -> Interface -> Toolbox** and uncheck **Use tool groups**.

[image: screenshot showing Appearance options in Toolbox menu]

### Before and After

[image: few tools] [image: many tools]

**Note**: The other answer is about Heal selection tool, which OP originally wanted to enable.

Comment: Exactly. That group thing caused trouble for many people. It was a bad idea to make it default.

Comment: Would it be under the stampy thingy when tool groups are enabled? (I don't use GIMP; I'm just guessing from the icon order.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes

Comment: Thank you Archisman Panigrahi. But I am talking about the Heal selection tool (Found in the Resyntehsizer plugin) not the standard Heal tool. The one that works like Photoshop's "Content Aware Fill"

Comment: @PramodMalawade Unfortunately I don't know how to enable the Heal selection tool. I have edited your question to add that information, so that someone else may answer it.

Comment: (bold for extra clarity, as this is important) **This answer is about the heal tool. The question is about the "heal selection" filter. They are not the same, and this answer does not help people get back the "heal selection" filter.**

Answer (score 0):

The heal selection is driven by Python plugins ("Heal selection" and "Heal transparency" menus) and these Python plugins require python v2, while on Ubuntu 20+ Python v2 is not installed by default, and there is no "gimp-python" package to add Python support to Gimp.

You can find gimp-python packages elsewhere, see:

https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Heal-Selection-Missing-from-Gimp-on-Ubuntu-20-04?pid=18354#pid18354

https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Python-script-support-missing-in-my-2-10-22-install

Answer (score 0):

The Gimp developers prefer Flatpak for distribution now. The recommended way, therefore, is to go to the Resynthesizer Github and follow the instructions there for installing the Flatpak Gimp and Resynthesizer which does include the "heal" tool. It works, but the disadvantage is that it's well over a GigaByte because the large Gimp flatpak depends on other large flatpaks.

At the time of writing, it's now early 2024 and Ubuntu version 23.10. Trying to fix this problem for the Gimp from Ubuntu's repository using the previously mentioned manual downloads of older Ubuntu packages has become more cumbersome than ever. I have made it work, though, and the whole installation including Gimp is only about 150MB.

Start off by deinstalling the newer gimp-plugin-registry (which doesn't contain tools like "heal"), and deinstall any trace of python2 that you've got left over from earlier versions of Ubuntu. Then run this script. It's for 64-bit PC systems, BTW. It assumes that you're starting from a complete desktop installation else some of the dependencies of the downloaded packages might not be met. It works for me, anyway.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Install gimp and dependencies for plugin-registry
sudo apt -y install gimp gimp-gmic
sudo apt -y install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 liblqr-1-0 libtiff-tools libtiff6

# Package for Ubuntu 20.04 which still contains resynthsizer
# gimp-plugin-registry_9.20180625ubuntu2_amd64.deb
# but has many dependencies that must be downloaded
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-defaults/python2-minimal_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-defaults/libpython2-stdlib_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-defaults/python2_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/what-is-python/python-is-python2_2.7.17-4_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.3.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libf/libffi7/libffi7_3.3-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gimp/gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gimp-plugin-registry/gimp-plugin-registry_9.20180625ubuntu2_amd64.deb

# Install Python2.7
sudo dpkg -i libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python2.7-minimal_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python2.7_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb

# Install Python2 meta-packages
sudo dpkg -i python2-minimal_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libpython2-stdlib_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python2_2.7.18-3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-is-python2_2.7.17-4_all.deb

# Install gimp-python dependencies
sudo dpkg -i libtiff5_4.3.0-6_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libffi7_3.3-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

# Install resynthesizer and its python scripts
sudo dpkg -i gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gimp-plugin-registry_9.20180625ubuntu2_amd64.deb

#stop ubuntu from updating the package
sudo apt-mark hold gimp-plugin-registry
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer contains errors, so here is the right format do download and install the important packages. It does work on my up to date Ubuntu 20.04 without problems (07.02.2021).

```
wget ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1+b1_amd64.deb
wget ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gimp/gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1+b1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry
rm python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1+b1_amd64.deb
rm gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb
```

Restart GIMP and enjoy the resynthesizer tool. :)

Comment: How is this different from my answer?